# migrating cakephp 1.3 to 2 .x lazy model error

Tags: php, cakephp, migration, cakephp-2.0, lazy-loading

I have followed this document to migrate from cakephp 1.3 to 2.X . I am getting this error .

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'LazyModel' not found in app/Model/AppModel.php

I checked in the file i can see this line. App::import('Lib', 'LazyModel');

Help me please

Comment: What document are you talking about? On a side note, models are not supposed to have a `Model` suffix (except for `AppModel`).

Answer (score 1):

Remove the Lazy stuff.
Cake2 brings this with it automatically.

Just make sure your models properly extend the AppModel from there on.
And the AppModel extends from Model.